# How to view local Pdf in PdfViewerActivity?

Tags: android, pdf

Im using this https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library
I have put 6 pdfs in my assets folder and try to load them from my tabactivity,
but the it keeps "Loading PDF Page" while I'm sure the pdf files aren't that big :P

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

setupTabHost();

}
private void setupTabHost() {
addTab("page1", R.drawable.thumbnail1, PdfActivity.class, 1);
addTab("page2", R.drawable.thumbnail2, PdfActivity.class, 2);
addTab("page3", R.drawable.thumbnail3, PdfActivity.class, 3);
addTab("page4", R.drawable.thumbnail4, PdfActivity.class, 4);
addTab("page5", R.drawable.thumbnail5, PdfActivity.class, 5);
addTab("page6", R.drawable.thumbnail6, PdfActivity.class, 6);
    }

private void addTab(String tag, int drawableId, Class<?> c, int pagenumber) {
//create tab
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag);

    //set layout
View thumbnail = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, getTabWidget(), false);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) thumbnail.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_icon);
icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
    spec.setIndicator(thumbnail);

//add intent
Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
                       intent.putExtra(net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "file:///android_asset/page"+pagenumber+".pdf");
spec.setContent(intent);

//add tab
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
     }
}


public class PdfActivity extends PdfViewerActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}



public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }
public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }
public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }
public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }
public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }
```

}

I've got this in my log, but I have page1.pdf in my asset folder for sure!

```
10-09 16:55:00.223: I/PDFVIEWER(3650): onCreate
10-09 16:55:00.223: E/PDFVIEWER(3650): restoreInstance
10-09 16:55:00.308: D/dalvikvm(3650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 168K, 4% free 12979K/13383K, paused 10ms+2ms
10-09 16:55:00.373: I/PDFVIEWER(3650): Intent { cmp=xxxx (has extras) }
10-09 16:55:00.378: I/PDFVIEWER(3650): ST='file 'file:///android_asset/page1.pdf' not found'
10-09 16:55:00.383: I/PDFVIEWER(3650): ST='reading page 1, zoom:1.0'
10-09 16:55:00.403: D/dalvikvm(3650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 107K, 3% free 13358K/13703K, paused 2ms+14ms
10-09 16:55:00.438: D/dalvikvm(3650): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 127K, 3% free 13626K/14023K, paused 13ms
10-09 16:55:00.573: D/dalvikvm(3650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 4% free 13963K/14407K, paused 2ms+24ms
```

Comment: sorry youre right! updated it

Comment: `file 'file:///android_asset/page1.pdf' not found` so not big that they don't exist

Comment: and still there IS a file called page1.pdf in the assets folder

Comment: I just saw in the pdfviewer code that it tries to make a File object and then checks if the file has data. When I doesnt find any data it outputs the "file not found" message

Comment: a quick solution would be to copy the file on the sdcard and view this file (assets can be tricky)

Comment: I need to make an app that has the pdf files built in

Comment: @JayBigguy: Facing same issue like you, did u got any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your file path. Remove `file://` from your path, like this:

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"bell.pdf");
String path = pdfFile.getAbsolutePath();
                openPdfIntent(path);

    protected void openPdfIntent(String path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME,path);
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

After looking through the source code and playing with it myself when I ran into a similar issue, I was able to get this to work by using the VIEW intent when calling the activity. Also, I had to use a certain path for the file, and I was only able to get it to pull from the `res\raw` folder. You may be able to tweak it to pull from the `asset` folder as well, but I never went that far.

```
// This is wherever you are launching the activity from another activity
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(this, PdfActivity.class);
pdfIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.your.package/raw/filename"), "application/pdf");

startActivity(pdfIntent);
```

When you use the VIEW action, that class actually pulls the file and stores it to a temporary directory so that it can view it properly.